# Run C program in mintty from the windows command line

Tags: command-line, cygwin, mintty

I want to run a C program in mintty and divert the `stderr` output stream to a file, debug.txt. This may be accomplished using:

```
./zombie_jump 2>debug.txt
```

However, I am having issues lauching this from the Windows command line.

```
mintty -s 70,55 ./zombie_jump 2>debug.txt
```

behaves as if the `2>debug.txt` was left off the command (running the program but not diverting the error stream), and

```
mintty -s 70,55 "./zombie_jump 2>debug.txt"
```

behaves as if I sent "./zombie_jump 2>debug.txt", producing the error `Failed to run ./zombie_jump 2>debug.txt: No such file or directory`.

What command should I be using?

Edit:

```
mintty -s 70,55 './zombie_jump 2>debug.txt'
```

returns `Failed to run ./zombie_jump : No such file or directory` and creates a file called `debug.txt'`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `mintty` wants separate parameters for the command it runs, so you need to quote the redirection. Without quotes the redirection applies to `mintty` itself, which I guess sets up new standard I/O paths. If you include the redirection in the same quotes as the command, then this becomes the whole command, looking for a single name with embedded blank and redirection characters. Single quotes have no special meaning in `cmd`, hence your last finding.

Comment: Two suggestions: `mintty -s 70,55 ./zombie_jump "2>debug.txt"` to stop the redirection in `cmd`; if this fails create `./zombie_noerrs` containing `./zombie_jump 2>debug.txt` and run `mintty -s 70,55 ./zombie_noerrs`.

Comment: Unfortunately the first suggestion doesn't work, same result as my second attempt above. The second isn't optimal either, as I'm trying to find a command I can use with Sublime Text 2 to run the current file I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is quite easy to understand: `mintty` doesn’t forward your programs output to (presumably) `cmd`, where the output redirection is set up. Instead, it displays output in its own GUI window. That’s what a terminal emulator is designed to do, after all. :)

Output redirection is a shell feature. If you just run `mintty my_command`, you’re not using a shell at all. Instead, `mintty` directly launches `my_command`.

If you quote `"my_command 2>out.err"`, you’re telling `mintty` to look for a command of that (whole) name. It is equivalent to typing `"my_command 2>out.err"` in a regular Linux shell. Won’t work either way.

So now that we’ve established it’s a shell feature, it’s clear we need a shell. A common choice would be Bash. Bash can be passed a command string to execute when it starts, like this:

```
bash -c "my_command 2>out.err"
```

That means we can use it like this with `mintty`:

```
mintty /bin/bash -c "my_command 2>out.err"
```

On my machine, the Cygwin Bash shell launched this way inherits the working directory I have in `cmd`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail, this is an excellent answer. When I tried bash (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38465/discussion-between-dimpl-and-davidpostill), I was missing the -c option, so received `no such file or directory` and `cannot execute binary file` errors.